# how to pass a php variable using form hidden input to another page using POST method?

Tags: php, html

This is page 2

```
    $var= $_GET['var'];
    $id= $_GET['id'];
    echo "Book Title:<br>" .$var. "<br> Book id:".$id."<br>";


    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookid='$id'");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<br><br>Author:<br>".$row['author'];
    echo "<br><br>Average rating is:<br>" .$row['avgrating'];

     }
    ?>  

    <form name='myForm' action='addreview.php' method='POST' >
    Give your reviews here:<br>
    <input type='textarea'  name='review' style='width: 500px; height:200px' ><br>
    <input type='hidden' id='ids' name='ids' value=''<?php echo $id ?> ''>
    <input type='SUBMIT' name='done' value='DONE'>
    </form>
```

on page 1 I am retrieving bookid from database and then passing it to  page 2, and then i have to pass it to page 3. on page 3 I am retrieving it with GET command but it is not working. Kindly help me

Comment: 1. If you are posting it, it won't be available via $_GET. You would use $_POST. 2. Sessions are better suited for this.

Comment: You should either change your form to use `method='GET'`, or change page 3 to retrieve it from $_POST

Comment: You can pass it to a $_SESSION or a $_COOKIE

Comment: i think you misspelled the attribute as [Mark](http://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) suggests.

Comment: i tried POST aswell But it is not working

Comment: i have a session of user , cant start another session for bookid, and if i use bookid in the same session it stores details for only one book which is not correct

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET` and `$_POST` in PHP correspond to the form `method=` in the HTML.  If your form's `method="POST"`, you must use `$_POST` to get to the value.

Comment: tried POST still not working, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You've got too many quotes:

```
<input type='hidden' id='ids' name='ids' value=''<?php echo $id ?> ''>
                                               ^^--                ^^--
```

That'll produce HTML that will be interepreted as (for an id of `8`):

```
<input [...snip...] value="" 8 "" />
```

`value` gets an an empty string, followed by an invalid attribute `8`, followed by a couple quotes that aren't a valid attribute OR value.

Comment: i have removed quotes still not working

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting page 1 via POST, you will need to access your submitted data using `$_POST`, not `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='hidden' id='ids' name='ids' value=''<?php echo $id ?> ''>
```

Look at your value:

```
value=''<?php echo $id ?>''
```

It shoud be

```
value='<?php echo $id; ?>'
```